# Which platform should I target for AdMob in Fire-OS App

Tags: android, admob, amazon-fire-os

I want to implement admob in my amazon app but when I go to create a banner on AdMob it only gives me the options to create a banner for android, ios & windows 8 so I was wondering which one should I pick since it will be going on the amazon app store.  I also had another question I was wondering if Amazon supports AdMobs mediation service where you can have several sources for that one ad unit through admob.com ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Amazon's Fire OS is forked from android so select "android" when creating your ads. And yes, Amazon supports admob's mediation service.

You can also use both admob and Amazon's mobile ads in your app. To do that you can follow their [official guide](https://developer.amazon.com/appsandservices/apis/earn/mobile-ads/docs/with-other-sdks)

Comment: how do i accept it? it doesnt let me upvote it says i require a reputation of 15 to upvote

Comment: 2020 and it doesn't work anymore. Admob ads can't show in the apps downloaded from Amazon appstore.